# Two http becoming one

Tags: http, url

I was just testing different ways to get the current URL, and suddenly i was concatenating two *http://* together, but i was seeing that in the browser it was http// (without the semicolon).

If you write in your navigation bar

> http://http://

It becomes

> http//

Does anybody knows why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the "robustness principle", i.e. "garbage in, something out".

What you're typing when you type `http://http://` should show you an error that you may want to reconsider the URI you just attempted to send a request to.

However, the browser sees these parts:

```
[scheme][://]host[:port][rest-of-uri]
```

So when you ask a browser to interpret `http://http://`, those parts end up being:

- scheme: `http`
- `://`: `://`
- host: `http` (second occurrence)
- `:port`: `:80`, defaulting the omitted port to 80.
- `rest-of-uri`: `//`

See [Wiki: Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).